# Ошибка триггера в Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Непонятная ошибка , что хочет не понятно . помогите разобраться

вот код ошибки "Compilation failed, line 7 (15:16:30) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare else elsif end exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with    << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array "

```
create or replace trigger stop_work
before insert or update or delete on sale
declare
e_arg exception;
e_arg2 exception;
BEGIN
if (to_char(sysdate,'month') || to_char(sysdate, 'dd')) in ('may09','january01','january07','february23','march08','may01','september01') then raise e_arg; 
if to_char(sysdate, 'day') in ('sunday','saturday') then raise e_arg2; end if;
EXCEPTION
when e_arg then _application_error(-20001, 'pora prazdnovat!!!!');
when e_arg2 then _application_error(-20001, 'Weekends!!!!');
END stop_work;
```

Comment: А  где ошибка? Приложите к вопросу пожалуйста код триггера.

Comment: весь код и ошибки пожалуйста прикладывайте текстом. Не очень удобно рассматривать картинки

Comment: Вот выложил. второй end if проблему не решает. Непонятная ошибка , не понятно что делать

Comment: А код когда добавите?

Comment: Добавил код тригера

Comment: Хорошо, что добавили код. Теперь, а почему вы пишете, что end if проблему не решает? Всё работает - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=20a1b7bf93fe9e9d4b71b474983d0e68).

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! не сталкивался еще с такой проблемой

Answer (score 2):

Ты забыл в 7 строке добавить end if